# twitter for android in-app browser disables opening the link with native app

Tags: android, twitter, in-app

I have an app with an intent filter that can open some web urls. It is working fine for links(www.butterflytv.net/player.php?streamUrl=...) with the intent filter below

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="www.butterflytv.net"
        android:pathPattern="/player.php.*"
        android:scheme="http" />
     <data
        android:host="butterflytv.net"
        android:pathPattern="/player.php.*"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

However when this link is in a tweet, twitter in-app browser opens the link. I want Android to open an app chooser to open the link. Do you know how to do this?

Thank you in advance,
A. Oguz

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

This will let you choose your application for opening the link.

Comment: I mean, I want twitter in-app browser to show app chooser.